# Unity - how to change the material of a torus mesh by percentage?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mesh

Ok, so basically I have a torus shaped mesh and I need it in Unity, depending on a value, to change its material around in a clockwise direction. Like this where the white is increasing in percentage:

[image]

I have no idea how to go about this as I have limited knowledge of dynamic shaders. Would I need to gradually show a separate object? Or how could I go about this?

Comment: Basically [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163476/unity-3d-texture-animated-round-circular-bar) except you'd make the texture match the torus's UVs so that the gradient falls across the surface you wish to alter, beyond that, exactly the same, all the way until the shader draws transparent. That'd you'd substitute for the secondary color.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could technically make a shader which calculates the angle to each pixel given an object center, your best bet would be to unwrap the torus in such a way that the travel direction of your transition is mapped to the X axis in UV space (see image). Then, you can expose a property in the range of 0 to 1 which represents the cutoff point in percent. Finally, in your fragment or surface function, you can do this:

```
if (i.uv.x - _Cutoff > 0) {
    // Material A
    col = tex2D(_TextureA, i.uv);
    roughness = _RoughnessA;
    // etc.
} else { 
    // Material B
    col = tex2D(_TextureB, i.uv);
    roughness = _RoughnessB;
}
```

You can then animate the _Cutoff property through C# script. What's even cooler is that you can use a mask texture to describe the transition, and offset its uv.x coord by your offset variable, and then use the color value to lerp between two material properties.

[image: torus unwrap]